# How can I contact Facebook for my account information?

Tags: facebook

A friend of mine gave away her Facebook password to someone whom she believes has used her Facebook account to harass others. She is now in trouble and we are trying to help her out.

The idea would be to obtain the IP used by her account to post those messages from Facebook's logs, then move from there.

The question, then, is how to contact Facebook to obtain this information. All forms from their help center that allow you to submit information seem to be (I presume) seldom-looked at, often with specific disclaimers that they will not respond to any information posted there. I would like a way to get in touch with someone for a fairly low-latency exchange, as time is a factor.

Comment: Just checking, but your friend has changed the password on their account by now, right?

Comment: Agreeing with @GKoe's answer below. Facebook, or any site for that matter, will and should not provide any logs, IP addresses, personal information, etc. without a police report or court order as evidence of an open case.

Answer (score 8):

All of Facebook's customer service is handled online, through the Help link at the bottom right of every Facebook page. Select the help topic relevant to your problem, then click the "Send us a message" link at the bottom of that help topic page. This will flag your issue specifically to your problem.

Phone: 650-543-4800

How to reach a live person:
Facebook does not currently offer telephone support. You can press 0 to leave a message, but not sure what that does.

EDIT: Facebook will not assist you with log files or other investigational information unless you provide a copy of a police report relating to the incident, or a court subpoena.